# Are there any meaningful use cases to assign undefined to a variable?

Tags: javascript

There are `null` and `undefined` in JavaScript. Are there any meaningful use cases of assigning `undefined` to a variable?

Answer (score 5):

Yes.

When a property had a value and now you want it to have none, you usually have those choices:

**delete:**

```
delete obj.prop;
```

Problem: it has [very big performance impacts](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#521-objects-that-are-in-hash-table-mode-aka-normalized-objects-dictionary-mode---objects-who-have-a-hash-table-as-a-backing-data-structure-are-not-simple-enumerables). It **is** one of the biggest performance killers in an otherwise well designed JS program. Track it and be sure to never use it when performance matters (note that the impact isn't just located where you delete the property but also where you read or write other properties of the object later on, including when calling methods).

**set the value to null:**

```
obj.prop = null;
```

This only makes semantic sense when the expected type of the value is "object" (or sometimes "string"). Note that there's a semantic difference between `null` (i.e. no object) and `undefined` (i.e. value unset).

**set the value to NaN:**

```
obj.prop = NaN;
```

You won't use this for anything except numbers (but then it can make a ton of sense, depending on the specific use case).

**set the value to undefined:**

```
obj.prop = undefined;
```

This is the best choice in most other cases. It also plays nicely with the usually right way to test whether an argument or argument's property has been set, that is to check `options.something === undefined`.

Comment: I didn't know the performance impact of `delete`. I appreciate other use cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like already explained in detail by @Denys :)

If I use `this.x = null` typeof x will be `object` which makes me use `undefined` for this.

There was a problem before ECMA 5 where you could change the value of `undefined` which is the only theoretical pitfall.

```
undefined = 'myEx';
```

```js
function myEx(){ 
    
    this.x = undefined;
  
    function isXExisting(){
        return typeof this.x !== "undefined";
    }
  
    function squareX(){
      switch(typeof this.x){
          case 'undefined': return undefined;
          case 'string': return this.x + this.x;
          case 'number': return this.x * this.x;
          case 'object': return this.x;
          default: return undefined;
      }
    }
    
    function setX(value){
        this.x = value;
    }
  
    function getX(){
        return this.x;
    }

    function resetX(){
        this.setX(undefined);
    }
     
     return{
       isXExisting: isXExisting,
       setX: setX,
       getX: getX,
       squareX: squareX,
       resetX: resetX
       }
  }

var y = new myEx();
console.log(y.isXExisting(), y.getX(), y.squareX());
y.setX(3);
console.log(y.isXExisting(), y.getX(), y.squareX());
y.setX('xX');
console.log(y.isXExisting(), y.getX(), y.squareX());
y.resetX();
console.log(y.isXExisting(), y.getX(), y.squareX());
```

Comment: Why do you use `undefined`? I think `null` fits better to represent an absence of a value.

Comment: @kawty if we want to find the `typeof` the variable and act upon accordingly `undefined` is preferred over `null` as `null` has the `type` of `object`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One more question, why do we want to use `typeof` to check the value? Isn't it sufficient `this.x === null` and use `null`?

Comment: @kawty check the above implementation of `squareX`. `undefined` came in handy for me over there compared to `null`.

Comment: I agree that it's handy to assign `undefined` when switching by `typeof` becuase `typeof null` is `object`. Thanks.